# How does Vim's autoread work?

Tags: vim

`:h autoread` says:

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.

After putting `set autoread` in my `vimrc`, I open a file with Vim, switch to another editor, change the file, and wait to see the changes in Vim as well. Nothing happens. I have to use `:e` to reload the file with the new content.

What did I miss?                                                                *I'm using Vim 7.2 on Mac 10.5.8*

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that :set autoread only works in a gui vim, not from the terminal.  I know this is an old question, but I had a very hard time finding any good help on this. The answer below with the WatchForChanges function is golden.

Comment: `autoread` can work in plain vim, inside a terminal emulator see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428958/5353461).

Comment: See also: [Can vim monitor realtime changes to a file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157914/can-vim-monitor-realtime-changes-to-a-file)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Autoread does not reload file unless you do something
like run external command (like !ls or !sh etc).
vim does not do checks periodically.
You can reload file manually using `:e`.

More details in this thread:
[Click here](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg05900.html)

Answer (score 42):

I use the following snippet which triggers autoread whenever I switch buffer or when focusing vim again:

```
au FocusGained,BufEnter * :silent! !
```

Also, it makes sense to use it in combination with the following snippet so that the files are always saved when leaving a buffer or vim, avoiding conflict situations:

```
au FocusLost,WinLeave * :silent! w
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to speed up the write by disabling any hooks that run on save (e.g. linters), you can prefix the `w` command with `noautocmd`:

```
au FocusLost,WinLeave * :silent! noautocmd w
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this solution, so added it to the vim wiki as well.

Comment: Why not use `:checktime` to explicitly trigger the check without shelling out? Also Vim should already be doing this on FocusGained, you shouldn't need an autocmd for that!

Comment: How would I add this to my .vimrc to make this behaviour default?

Comment: @StevieP [Here](https://github.com/fphilipe/dotfiles/blob/64c0921d3601edf8c2a59e24097a80f430ad215c/vimrc#L183-L188) the relevant lines in my .vimrc.

Comment: Right on. Thanks @fphilipe!

Comment: a bit more aggressive: `au InsertLeave * :slient! w`

Comment: @Ben +1 for using `checktime` rather than `!`. Otherwise, my neovim (run in terminal) does not do this automatically on FocusGained

Comment: We could use `update` in place of `w` to write when the buffer has been modified.

Comment: @Brij or `wa` (short for `wall`), which "write[s] all changed buffers".

Answer (score 21):

As per [my posting on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/181377/auto-reloading-a-file-in-vim-as-soon-as-it-changes-on-disk/370814#370814)

Autoread just doesn't work. Use the following.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Have_Vim_check_automatically_if_the_file_has_changed_externally

I got the best results by calling the setup function directly, like so.

```
let autoreadargs={'autoread':1} 
execute WatchForChanges("*",autoreadargs)
```

The reason for this, is that I want to run a ipython/screen/vim setup.

Comment: Finally! I have tried quite a few suggestions for getting something like this to work, but none worked in a terminal. This gets the job done!  Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

A bit late to the party, but vim nowadays has timers, and you can do:

```
if ! exists("g:CheckUpdateStarted")
    let g:CheckUpdateStarted=1
    call timer_start(1,'CheckUpdate')
endif
function! CheckUpdate(timer)
    silent! checktime
    call timer_start(1000,'CheckUpdate')
endfunction
```

Comment: This worked the best for me, and covers all cases, it seems. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that did the trick: I executed `prettier --write *` and all my files opened in vim get updated immediately - no need to change mode from normal to insert or do other things to see changes like in other answers.

Comment: While other solutions that are ranked higher gave me headache and still did not work properly, this one worked directly just by copying the code, and it works like a charm. This should be the top answer.

Comment: Well, it didn't work for me.

Comment: This is the one!

Comment: With `silent!` it will keep running if there's an error, right?

Also, is there any reason not to use the [`repeat` parameter](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#:~:text=dictionary.%20%20Supported%20entries%3A%0A%09%09%20%20%20%22-,repeat,-%22%09Number%20of%20times)?

Answer (score 12):

Outside of gvim, autoread doesn't work for me.

To get around this I use this rather ugly hack.

```
set autoread
augroup checktime
    au!
    if !has("gui_running")
        "silent! necessary otherwise throws errors when using command
        "line window.
        autocmd BufEnter        * silent! checktime
        autocmd CursorHold      * silent! checktime
        autocmd CursorHoldI     * silent! checktime
        "these two _may_ slow things down. Remove if they do.
        autocmd CursorMoved     * silent! checktime
        autocmd CursorMovedI    * silent! checktime
    endif
augroup END
```

This seems to be what the script irishjava linked to does, but that lets you toggle this for buffers. I just want it to work for everything.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your comment reminded me that I posted this. Thought I would update the code as it didn't work well when using the command-line window (`q:`).

Comment: This works great! Can I ask though if you know of a way to get it to write a timestamp of when the file was read in (and the buffer reloaded) when `checktime` does its thing? That would be nice.

Answer (score 11):

#### Trigger when cursor stops moving

Add to your `vimrc`:

```
au CursorHold,CursorHoldI * checktime
```

By default, [CursorHold](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorHold) is triggered after the cursor remains still for 4 seconds, and is configurable via [updatetime](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'updatetime').

#### Buffer change trigger

To have `autoread` trigger when changing buffers, add to your `vimrc`:

```
au FocusGained,BufEnter * checktime
```

#### Terminal window focus trigger

To have `FocusGained` (see above) work in plain vim, inside a terminal emulator (Xterm, tmux, etc) install the plugin:
[vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events)

On tmux versions > 1.9, you'll need to add in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g focus-events on
```

Comment: See the longer, sister answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383044/143394).

Comment: CursorHold and CursorHoldI  only trigger once, they do not retrigger every "updatetime".

Answer (score 1):

for me it works when i use the command

```
:set autoread
```

Of course you have to save the file in the other editor before anything happens.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old but hopefully this will help someone like myself that came across a similar issue.

I don't know how autoload works but I do know how vimscript works which is usually how get things
done. If you find this useful, upvote. To answer your question, don't edit the same file in other
editors. Usually you will get a notification in vim if you want to reload the file. I was having
this problem but my problem was different. I wanted to reload a css file after compiling it with
hugo from scss. This is what I did, you can take my code ideas and make them work for your needs.

**Usage**

1. Change style.scss to the file you're working on and add a pattern to
   autoload_files, these are the files you want to autoload. In my case I want to reload a file that
   ends with the extension 'content'.
2. In the autocmd include the files that you're going to write, in my case 'style.scss'.
3. Change the delay from 500 ms to whatever you want.

```
function! AutoLoadFiles(timer) abort
    let found_ids = []
    let autoload_files = ['content$'] "The files you want to autoload
    let openBuffers=map(gettabinfo(tabpagenr())[0].windows,{idx,val->getwininfo(val)[0]['bufnr']})
    for buf in openBuffers
    let name =  bufname(buf)
        for pat in autoload_files
            if match(name,pat) != -1 
                let fid = getbufinfo(buf)[0].windows[0]
                call add(found_ids,fid)
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
    for id in found_ids
        call win_execute(id,'edit')
    endfor
call timer_stop(a:timer)
endfunction
augroup AutoLoadFiles
    autocmd!
    au BufWrite *style.scss let s:delay_timer = timer_start(500, 'AutoLoadFiles',{'repeat':1})
augroup end
```