# Best way to view multiple logs at once?

Tags: linux, logging, emacs, concatenation, cat

I am currently running zookeeper processes and multiple internal processes and they all print out to their own log files as text. I am pretty green to linux but I was wondering if viewing multiple log file in a single screen without switching between emacs windows or vim windows is an issue for other. What is the best way to view say 3, four or more log files at once? Would it involve the CAT or | commands?

Comment: `lnav` is easy to install and use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are viewing live logs you can use `tail` with multiple files, or just tail an entire directory using the wildcard operator.

If you are digging though logs you can use Terminator, it is in the Debian repos, to open multiple terminal sessions in one window.

If you are feeling more adventurous your can use `tmux` to split your terminal window, the great thing about tmux is that is works in textmode, so you can do it over ssh. Here is a pretty decent tmux split pane tutorial http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/tmux-tutorial-split-terminal-windows-easily

Answer (score 2):

i like **multitail** as an optional but nice way to monitor multiple files whithout a lot of hacking around. After installing (e.g. apt-get install multitail) run `multitail file1.log file2.log file3.log`. the 'f1' key gives you inline help which keys to press.

But, if you want to **stay in vim** you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296697/4940240):

One can run this oneliner from ex (whithin vim) when needed (or put each command in vimrc, for when log-files are opened.)

`:set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("lh")`

Explanation:
- **autoread**: reads the file when changed from the outside (but it doesnt work on its own, there is no internal timer or something like that. It will only read the file when vim does an action, like a command in ex `:!`
- **CursorHold * checktime**: when the cursor isn't moved by the user for the time specified in 'updatetime' (which is 4000 miliseconds by default) checktime is executed, which checks for changes from outside the file
- **call feedkeys("lh")**: the cursor is moved once, right and back left. and then nothing happens (... which means, that CursorHold is triggered, which means we have a **loop**)

Answer (score 0):

It hit me out of nowhere... I should just import the log folder directory into an empty project in eclipse, then I can swiftly explore and inspect logs and split the screens as needed across multiple monitors. All of Leon's answer is good stuff too, but since I am already using Eclipse heavily I might as well take advantage of that locality.