# Vim autoread without changing cursor position

Tags: vim

I have autoread working via my .vimrc:

```
set autoread
au CursorHold,FocusGained,BufEnter * checktime
```

When vim reloads a buffer due to it having changed, it both scrolls the buffer and changes the current cursor position to a seemingly random point in the file, although occasionally it stays in the same place. I have experimented with it, but no pattern is apparent.

Is there a way to prevent this, or to save and restore the cursor position when reloading?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to save the view and then restore it:

```
function! Checktime() abort
    let l:winview = winsaveview()
    checktime
    call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction

augroup Autoread
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorHold,FocusGained,BufEnter * call Checktime()
augroup END
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296697/4940240) answer: to prevent the cursor moving away from its current position you can call feedkeys["lh"] (it moves the cursor to the right and back to the left, which normaly doesn't do harm when viewing a file)

```
:set autoread | au CursorHold * checktime | call feedkeys("lh")
```

respectively

```
:set autoread | au CursorHold,FocusGained,BufEnter * checktime | call feedkeys("lh")
```

(it works in my environment)